# Save fieldset state in form

Tags: forms

I've build a custom module and a custom form with form API. 
I also allow users to come back and edit so I re-populate their old values.

The issue I have is that some of the form is in a collapsible fieldset, how do I save the users' fieldset state so I can open it op again for them when they go to edit the form?